# Get Highest Sal rows according to empid wise in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables

```
Employee
---------------
ID Name
1  John 
2  Kelly
3  Leo

Dept
-------
ID  Name
1   Finance
2   A/c
3   Marketing


Accout
--------------------
Id EmpId Dept Sal
1   1     1    25,000
2   1     2    30,000
3   2     2    20,000
4   2     1    15,000
5   3     3    20,000
```

Now i need to get highest salary row with appropriate data.

Like for Emp id 1 highest sal = 30,0000 so get whole row id = 2 from a/c table
         Emp id 2 highest sal = 20,000  so get whole row id = 3 from a/c table

I try with

```
SELECT E.id,E.name AS emp_name,D.name AS dept_name,
        A.Dept as dept_id,max(A.sal) AS max_sal 
FROM Accout A 
    JOIN Employee E ON A.EmpId = E.ID 
    JOIN Dept D ON A.Dept = D.Id 
Group by EmpId
```

So i got result like

```
Id  emp_name dept_name dept_id max_sal
1     John     Finance   1      30,000
2     Kelly     A/c      2      20,000
3     Leo    Marketing   3      20,000
```

But i need result like this

```
Id  emp_name dept_name dept_id max_sal
1     John       A/c     2      30,000
2     Kelly     A/c      2      20,000
3     Leo    Marketing   3      20,000
```

Please let me know how it's possible so i can got the correct output.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the max salary row first and then join with other tables. 
This query should work for you.

```
SELECT 
    E.id, E.name AS emp_name, D.name AS dept_name, A.Dept AS dept_id, max_sal
FROM
    Accout A
    JOIN
    (SELECT 
        EmpId, MAX(sal) AS max_sal FROM
        Accout GROUP BY EmpId
    ) B ON A.EmpId = B.EmpId AND A.sal = B.max_sal
    JOIN Employee E ON A.EmpId = E.ID
    JOIN Dept D ON A.Dept = D.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `GROUP BY`, I used `ORDER BY` since you said you just want the highest to lowest salary, plus I removed `max()`:

```
SELECT E.id
        E.name AS emp_name,
        D.name AS dept_name,
        A.DeptId as dept_id,
        A.sal AS max_sal
FROM Account A
JOIN Employee E ON A.EmpId = E.ID
JOIN Dept D ON A.DeptId = D.Id
ORDER BY max_sal DESC
LIMIT 3
```

You can use `LIMIT` if you want to limit the returned rows

Comment: It's display all record i need to 3 record as you describe in example.
Need to display unique employee wise

Comment: @InSystemGrp Check edit, that should the display to 3 rows

Comment: I checked it display the 5 results instead of 3

Comment: @InSystemGrp Did you add the `LIMIT 3`?